# Add Wysiwyg Field in 'Contact From 7' : without using "Contact Form 7 : Wysiwyg Field" plugin

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I have create one wordpress blog website. And as per requirement, I have to active **Contact Form 7 : Wysiwyg Field** plugin for add **Wysiwyg Field** in 'Contact From 7'.

But after active **Contact Form 7 : Wysiwyg Field** plugin Wysiwyg field show in form panel(as below image yellow mark).

[image]

And when i'm add this "Wysiwyg" field on form. it's display

**Blank Area**

OR

`Warning: Parameter 1 to wpcf7_tg_pane_wysiwyg() expected to be a reference, value given in C:\xampp\htdocs\XYZ\wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7\admin\includes\tag-generator.php on line 68`.

Your help would be appreciated.